# Network provider in android?

Tags: android, location

I working on getlocation in my app.I was thinking 3 way to get location.GPS,(3g,wifi) and cell tower trangulation.But i see 2 provider in android.Network and GPS provider.My question is network provider getting data (3g,wifi) and cell tower i think.How can it do that? For example if i connect 3g what is prefer first 3g or cell tower.And i havent got any internet connection i can get current location right? Or getting cache data(last location)?

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You are right there is 3 ways to get location GPS , 3G(Cell tower) and wifi, the Network provider gets the locations for the 3G and the wifi(Some times it is more accurate than GPS), it is gonna listen for the one that is  connected at the moment, but if both are enabled the cell phone gives preference to the wifi.

Answer (score 0):

> if i connect 3g what is prefer first 3g or cell tower

Why do you think 3G doesn't use cell towers? With network provider you will get locations from both cell towers and wifi

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the quality of the Network provider can vary quite a bit.

As mentioned, the network provider uses a combination of WiFi and Cell tower information to provide location information.

If you happen to be close to a Wifi network, which is common in urbanized areas, but not outside of cities, you usually get a very good accuracy.

However, outside of range of a Wifi, you're at the mercy of the cell towers. Here, the precision depends on the quality and features of the cell tower, as well as the amount of cell towers that can be used to triangulate your position.

In these situations, the quality can vary alot, both between locations, but also depending on which Carrier you use.

My application runs in Sweden, and in some areas of our country, a carrier might have only one tower within a very large area. In those cases, all lon/lat fixes end up directly on the tower, with a precision of even up to 20.000 - 30.000 meters.